# How am I supposed to farm coralcreep?

Tags: starbound

I obtained Coralcreep seeds as a quest item. I am supposed to farm them and deliver the crops.

After I planted seeds on standard watered tilted soil, they popped out instantly. I figured maybe it's an underwater plant and needs to grow under water. So I made this pit:

[image: image description]

I assumed that the plant will be fine underwater. But if I try to plant it, the blueprint glow is red, indicating I cannot place it there:

[image: image description]

This is even though Starbounder wiki seems to suggest that underwater is where this plant belongs:

> Coralcreep seeds must be planted in water onto tilled soil. The planted Coralcreeps will return to seeds once they touch the air.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough water? Try filling one more tile's worth of water and then see if you can plant.

Comment: Excellent question post.  I can't imagine how you can even describe what is wrong without knowing that you need a 4 tile deep pool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track with creating a pool to plant your coralcreep. But it needs some more headspace.

Make your pool at least 4 tiles deep. You will then be able to grow underwater crops successfully. The reason you can't plant isn't that there isn't enough water, it is the platform above it which prevents placing the seed. However, you still need more water or the seed will still pop out when growing too high. Here is a screenshot of a working setup:

[image: Starbound water farm]